# Today Widget El Capitan Working, Yosemite Not Showing Up

Tags: macos, swift, today-extension, osx-today-widget

So I've built this 95% finished app, but I'm running into a few problems.

The function widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler is NEVER being called until I press the red x in the simulator, so I am having to use 'view did appear' instead of the proper "apple way" of updating information (The way that worked on Yosemite).

Secondly, when testing on Yosemite, the Today View widget did not have any content, like the image below:

[image]

Please, any help will be appreciated.